# What made G-d change His opinion about Humans and how is it possible?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, reward-punishment, parashat-noach, mabul

> וַיָּ֣רַח ה' אֶת־רֵ֣יחַ הַנִּיחֹחַ֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר ה' אֶל־לִבּ֗וֹ
>   לֹֽא־אֹ֠סִף לְקַלֵּ֨ל ע֤וֹד אֶת־הָֽאֲדָמָה֙ בַּעֲב֣וּר הָֽאָדָ֔ם כִּ֠י יֵ֣צֶר לֵ֧ב הָאָדָ֛ם רַ֖ע מִנְּעֻרָ֑יו וְלֹֽא־אֹסִ֥ף ע֛וֹד לְהַכּ֥וֹת אֶת־כָּל־חַ֖י כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר עָשִֽׂיתִי׃
>
> The LORD smelled the pleasing odor, and the LORD said to Himself: “Never again will I doom the earth because of man, since the devisings of man’s mind are evil from his youth; nor will I ever again destroy every living being, ([Gen 8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.21?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

IIRC, G-d created the Man with [a certain measure of] bad inclination and didn't make any changes to the plan since. According to Rambam ([Yesodot 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) G-d is unchangeable:

> וְכֵיוָן שֶׁנִּתְבָּרֵר שֶׁאֵינוֹ גּוּף וּגְוִיָּה יִתְבָּרֵר שֶׁ...**אֵינוֹ מִשְׁתַּנֶּה שֶׁאֵין לוֹ דָּבָר שֶׁיִּגְרֹם לוֹ שִׁנּוּי.**
>   Since it is clear that He is Incorporeal, it clearly follows that ... nor He undergoing any change as there is naught to cause any change in Him;

So what happened after the Mabul that G-d didn't know before and how it is reconciled with Rambam?

Comment: Rambam says that G-d cannot change. G-d cannot have regrets. This story can and should be read the way Rabbi Ishmael understands the Bible dibra torah
k’lashon b’nei adam, “the Torah speaks in the language of man.”